# Android - how to parse html by jsoup and fill into the arraylist?

Tags: java, android

I want to read the date from this HTML link:
 http://jadvalbaz.blog.ir/post/%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D9%84-%D8%AC%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%81-%D8%B0

if you look at the view-source

ذات اریه (پنومونی- سینه پهلو)ذر (مورچه ریز)ذرع (مقیاس طول)ذره ای بنیادی از رده هیبرونها که بار الکتریکی ندارد (لاندا)ذره منفی اتم (الکترون)ذریه (نسل)ذل (خواری)ذم (نکوهش)ذهاب (رفتن)ذی (صاحب)

my words are separated by <.br>, I want to read each word to ArrayList, I means how to omit the <.br> and read the words.

here is my code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();     
       for (Element span : document.select("?").select("?")) {
               title = span.toString();                 
              name.add(title);
           }
```

How to read them, what to put instead of question mark.
any suggestion?

Comment: You don't need 2 `select()`, Just 1 select will do.

Can you please post a small sample of html and what you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

edit the css of your template and define a class for your words then Use the `Element.select(String selector)` and `Elements.select(String selector)` method.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

  Element masthead = doc.select("p.words").first(); // p with class=words
```

follow below link for more information about extracting data with this methods:

[Use selector-syntax to find elements](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: if you pay attention I just want to read them into arraylist.my problem is that I can not read them with this tag <br>

Comment: I can not understand your code would you please explain more ?

Comment: in blog.ir you can add custom css... define a class and use this methods ...
if you dont know how to use this method check my answer an follow the link of documentation